# System.loadLibrary works on OpenJDK but not on Oracle

Tags: java, c++, linux

I implemented a SDK in C++ (API exported in C). This SDK compiles into a DLL for Windows and a .so for Linux. I also implemented a Java wrapper using JNA. This wrapper ships with .so and DLL inside it and I check at runtime which operation system is running and extract it on a folder specified by developer. It works well.

The problem is that one of customers that use Linux (I have just a couple of them on Linux) said that the library was not loading with a undefined symbol error. Here is the error:

***java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/libBXSDK.so: /usr/lib/libBXSDK.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE***

Initially I thought this could be related to some standard .so not being present. I then sent him a a very basic C++ executable and asked him to run. It worked. I then sent him a very basic Java application that DOES NOT use the SDK, but only calls System.loadLibrary("BXSDK"). After copying libBXSDK.so to /usr/lib, he ran the basic Java application and the error was the same.

I then decided to check his Java version, and realized he was using Oracle JDK latest version, and I saw that on my test environment that runs CentOS 7 (customer runs RHEL 7) I use OpenJDK. Immediately I installed Oracle JDK on my test environment and I saw the same problem.

So, my question is. What is the difference between Oracle JRE and OpenJDK (JRE), that causes this issue? Am I doing something wrong on my .so that OpenJDK is able to handle but Oracle JRE is not?

Thanks

Comment: `c++filt` translates that mangled name as `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info`. I suspect this may have something to do with which standard C++ library you link against, or way in which you invoke the compiler, or missing flags.

Comment: But what I don't understand is that if it is a problem with the way I build the .so, why it works with the C++ executable AND with OpenJDK loading it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify if the folder is the case as mentioned in this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1323888

Fellow (dontexist) member's comment is quite valid in general, the fact that OpenJDK being able to make the calls makes me think if library load itself was unsuccessful.

I figured, this may not entail an answer to the question - "What is the difference between Oracle and Open JDK in loading semantics".  Not sure if I can retract this post being an answer, but let others take the opportunity to explain about it.